# How to make C2DM app run all time,not getting the notification?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am using C2DM application,I got registered in Google & the app is running fine when it is running.When I exit the app to the home screen I dont get any notification from the server or when I come back to the app I dont get the messages which should be in queue.Which part am I should be missing now ,help me on this.

Comment: you might need to post some code from your implementation on the phone to make sure everything looks good. the answer below is the best i could think of without any code to work with.

Comment: I have followed everything from web,which part you need me to post,kindly tell me I ll do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what phone your testing with but make sure background data is enabled on your phone that was a problem for me in my implementation of c2dm. i saw this on the thunderbolt am sure other phones have this option.

Comment: I am using LG optimus p501 only,it also carries the google logo at its rear.I have also got the background data enabled in the settings.